# How to get child from array with dynamic parent in php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```
Array
(
[123] => Array
    (
        [shipment_id] => 123456
    )
)
```

I need the value from shipment_id, but I don't always know the array name '123' since it's different for each shipment.

I'm trying:

```
$array = $order->get_meta('_shipments');
echo $array[123]['shipment_id']; <- Works
echo $array[0]['shipment_id']; <- Doesn't work
echo $array['']['shipment_id']; <- Doesn't work
echo $array[]['shipment_id']; <- Doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_values`

This will return all the values of an array

```
$arr = array (
    "123" => array (
        "shipment_id" => 123456
    )
);

$arr = array_values($arr); //Convert assoc array to simple array

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $arr );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [shipment_id] => 123456
        )

)
```

You can now access as `$arr[0]['shipment_id']`

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Comment: Your solution works but I wanted to give other possibility to solve this issue :)

Comment: @Syscall Sure man. This what makes SO great, we can suggest different ways to solve the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_column like array_column($array,'column_name'), this results in getting all the values of column from multi-dimensional array.

```
<?php
$testArray = array(array('ids'=>1,'q'=>'hi'),array('ids'=>2,'q'=>'test')); 
$ids = array_column($testArray,'ids');
print_r($ids);
?>
```